# Angular injection (unknown provider)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get some json data from my server api. The url is /contacts.
I am getting an error about unknown provider but I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. I have amended the code again but it seems to happen again.

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', 'Contacts', '$http']);

  app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          templateUrl: "partials/main.html",
          controller: "contactsCtrl"
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});

  });
  
  app.service('Contacts', function($scope, $http) {
    this.data = null;

    this.all = function() {
      $http.get('/contacts').
       success(function(data) {
         $scope.contacts = data;
      })
    };
  });
  
  app.controller('contactsCtrl', function($scope, Contacts) {
    Contacts.all().query(function(data) {
      $scope.contacts = data;
    });
  });
  
  
}());
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>Firstname <input type="search" class="pull-right"></th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
      <td>
        <a ng-href="/edit/{{ contact.firstname }}">{{ contact.firstname }}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `Contacts` is a service, service can't be dependency for module, so just remove it from here `angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', 'Contacts', '$http']);`

Comment: Thank you very much as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently injecting Contacts as a new module here:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', 'Contacts', '$http']);
```

You don't need this as Contacts is a service and part of the same module. Update this line to:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute', '$http']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular modules work by injecting them into your application here.

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute']);
```

What you need to do would look like this.

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ngRoute','http']);
```

Here is an example of a working http request I'm currently using in a project of mine.

```
  var data = $.param({
      workers: JSON.stringify({
          user_name: "name",
          password: "work",
          email: "work@work"
      })
  });

  $http.post("http://ec2-xx-x-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/user/reg", data).success(function(data, status) {          
      $scope.user = data.user_name;
      $scope.email = data.email;
      $scope.access_token = data.access_token;
  });
```

Comment: I have now amended the code as per your suggestion. It keeps happening. Any ideas. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're trying to inject `$scope` into your `service`.

> Scope is the glue between application controller and the view.

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Instead of

```
app.service('Contacts', function($scope, $http) {
  this.all = function() {
    $http.get('/contacts').
     success(function(data) {
       $scope.contacts = data;
    })
  };
});
```

Try

```
app.service('Contacts', function($http) {
  this.all = function() {
    return $http.get('/contacts');
  };
});
```

Instead of

```
app.controller('contactsCtrl', function($scope, Contacts) {
  Contacts.all().query(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
  });
});
```

Try

```
app.controller('contactsCtrl', function($scope, Contacts) {
  Contacts.all().then(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
  });
});
```